# How do I make a splash screen load once?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

So... I've developed a splash screen which is running successfully. How can I make it run once (and only once)? I'd like to build a registration screen but I only want it to appear for the user once.

Help!

Amani Swann

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.nfc.linkingmanager.R;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 1000; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    Handler handler = new Handler();


    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {



            finish();

            if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NewCore.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
           }

        }

    }, SPLASH_DURATION);

}

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
    super.onBackPressed();

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the fact that the screen has already been displayed; upon start, you check this and if so, you replace the Activity by starting the next one and calling [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) for the splash screen immediately.

Comment: I've updated my source code to include SharedPreferences but it keeps crashing... any suggestions?

LOGCAT & JAVA:

http://copytaste.com/b2753

Comment: @user2163126 It's really hard to tell from the unformatted texts but the Java source does not make much sense and that also seems to be the exception -- how do you even get this run, it's not even a valid Java program?

Comment: It runs fine before adding the shared preferences.

Comment: UPDATED SOURCE (EASIER TO READ)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HW7jdyiRdepzwGLbuzCPCuKvvOPkNp0H4asCC4Yi9IU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2163126 Thanks for the update. -- There are a lot of things wrong with the code, actually. Do you understand Android's handling of the Activity lifecycle? When do you expect Android to execute code which you place outside of a lifecycle callback?

Comment: Yes - but I'm very new to everything. 

I thought that storing the flag as mentioned in the comment below would execute the new activity if 'SplashFlag' came back as false upon loading the layout which would then trigger the alternate activity instead of the one mentioned below which was including in the single working splash screen I had before. 

P.S.

I understand I called .NewCore 2x, I switched it from the new activity I created back to .NewCore to ensure the force close wasn't a problem w the new activity I created. (Just testing on an activity I know is stable - apologies for the typo!)

Comment: Should it look more like this?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1duKnieRamjiDhaaQbHrz5pjUzLK90Hui4ZJMSfu4BCs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is driving me crazy... (I know I'm getting close to finding a solution!)

Comment: I think I figured it out... but now none of my MenuItems are appearing - would you mind taking a look?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489377/splash-screen-causes-menuitems-not-to-appear

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a flag in shared preferences like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this );
finish();
if (prefs.getBoolean("SplashFlag", false)&&!mIsBackButtonPressed){

 Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NewCore.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
}else {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("SplashFlag", true); // value to store
//again there are values for int, long, string, float, boolean
editor.commit();//This is needed or the edits will not be put into the prefs file
}
```

Comment: I've added your code just after my "public class SplashScreen extends Activity {" 

but I'm getting an error stating "preferences cannot be resolved"


...any suggestions? : )

Comment: It's also force closing... (I've included my LOGCAT and updated java w the SharedPreferences snippet you posted above)

http://copytaste.com/b2753

Comment: I think I figured it out... but now none of my MenuItems are appearing - would you mind taking a look?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489377/splash-screen-causes-menuitems-not-to-appear

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) where you could store a `boolean` for instance `seenSplash` which you could default false. Then use an if that checks if it's false and then shows the splash. After a user has seen the splashscreen get an `Editor` where you change that boolean to true.

Don't forget to `commit()` the change on the editor.

Comment: I tried this... but my app is force closing. If you'd like to take a look I've included a copy of my LOGCAT and my updated JAVA 

http://copytaste.com/b2753

Comment: Sorry, but your code is a mess with that copytaste. Take a look at SplashScreen.java:16. 
There's several examples on the internet with SplashScreens and SharedPreferences. I guess you have an NPE for not declaring them correctly (guess, not based on the code or logcat)

Comment: Do you know of a good one? I just googled around a bit and didn't find any.

Comment: Look into your crash, google that reason and you will most likely find the solution. It was a long time ago I looked into that myself. Now I just write it myself and no, I really don't want to do someone elses job.

Answer (score 0):

in your register screen get login details and compare with values which you have saved in shared preferences. or hard-code like username is admin and password is admin. is both values are true just to enter splash screen otherwise redirect to other page whatever you like.

Comment: Hi! I'm still having trouble with this... I've added the code suggested above but it still fails. (Any suggestions?)

JAVA:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NHYEnkOjApa9RtTVCF6AJvmry6nFjZivNA0nnQ1oifQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is by far not the best way of achieving this, most splash screens load prior to login screens so by the time it gets to the login screen it is to late.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that

1st

```
finish();
SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
```

2nd in Your Android Manifest
where you declared your splash screen activity

add this

```
android:noHistory=true
```

Comment: I think I have a pretty different understanding of what the original poster actually asked.

Comment: I tried this (it seemed simple and straightforward) but it's not working. It still loads the same way it did before.

ANDROID MANIFEST: 
http://copytaste.com/t2752

SPLASH SCREEN JAVA (w your suggested changes)

http://copytaste.com/w2752

Comment: Any suggestions? (I'm really not sure how I would go about using the other suggested methods. I'm pretty new to android development)

Comment: @user2163126 What this suggestion achieves (in both variants) is that your splash screen will not appear in the Activity history. It is totally unrelated to your question if you ask me.

Comment: Ok - I'm watching an Android tutorial on SharedPreferences - I'll get back to you after I figure out how to implement SharedPreferences into my source code. 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UC2wAuxECw0

Comment: Hi! I'm still having trouble with this... I've added the code suggested above but it still fails. (Any suggestions?)

JAVA:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NHYEnkOjApa9RtTVCF6AJvmry6nFjZivNA0nnQ1oifQ/edit?usp=sharing